# Python. Почему выводит ошибку unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'map' в моём коде ? Пожайлуста подскажите

Tags: python, типы

Для решения задачи -

> "Задан круг (x-a)2+(y-b)2 = R2 и точки Р(р1, р2), F(f1, f1), L(l1,
> l2). Выяснить и вывести на экран, сколько точек лежит внутри круга.
> Проверка, лежит ли точка внутри круга, оформить посредством функции"

Я написал такой код -

```
def is_inside_circle(c_x, c_y, p_x, p_y, r):
    c = ((p_x - c_x) **2 + (p_y - c_y) **2)
    r2 = r * r
    if c <= r2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

p1, p2 = map(int,input("Введіть кординати точки \"P\"(x і y, через пробіл):").strip().split())
f1, f2 = map(int,input("Введіть кординати точки \"F\"(x і y, через пробіл):").strip().split())
l1, l2 = map(int,input("Введіть кординати точки \"L\"(x і y, через пробіл):").strip().split())
r = map(int,input("Введіть радіус окружності:"))

count = 0

if is_inside_circle(0, 0, p1, p2, r) == 1:
    count += 1
elif is_inside_circle(0, 0, f1, f2, r) == 1:
    count += 1
elif is_inside_circle(0, 0, l1, l2, r) == 1:
    count += 1

print(f"Кількість точок що лежать всередині кола: {count}")
```

Но выводит ошибку

> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'map'

Можете пожалуйста подсказать из за чего это ошибка появляется и как её можно решить

Comment: `map(int,'1')` - что вы ожидаете получить в r? Если уж очень хочется через map `r, = map(int,'1')` (Вместо 1 везде input())

Comment: @splash58 r - радиус, пользователь вводит радиус окружности и это записывается в переменную которая передаётся в функцию, в самой функции идёт подсчёт по формуле "(x-a)2+(y-b)2 = R2"

Comment: я же вам написал, как правильно получить радиус

Comment: @splash58, прощу прощения, не до конца прочитал, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем как мне подсказал человек [splash58](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180637/splash58), надо писать

```py
r, = map(int,input())
```

либо

```py
r = (float)(input())
```

Comment: (float) мммда... Извращенец

Comment: @eri А можно как то по другому ?

Comment: int(input()), float(input())  скобки вокруг функции не нужны. Это путает

Comment: @eri , понял, спасибо